# Как сделать чтобы при записи через JPA в id значения записывались по порядку

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;
    @Column(name = "password", length = 1000)
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role", columnDefinition = "default 'USER'")
    private Role role = Role.USER;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "User: [id=%d, name='%s', email='%s']",
                id, name, email);
    }
}
```

Не могу понять как сделать чтобы при записи в ID значения записывались по порядку с учетом пропущенных, т.е:
у меня есть записи 1, 2, 3, 7, 8.
когда я отправляю запрос у меня запись в id идет 9, 10 и тд.
как сделать чтобы запись шла в 4?
В таблице Id - not null, serial, primary key.
Пробовал @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE), результат тот же.
Или пробелы в таблице это жизненные реалии и исправлять это не имеет смысла?

Comment: *когда я отправляю запрос у меня запись в id идет 9, 10 и тд. как сделать чтобы запись шла в 4?* ID - это же автоинкрементный первичный ключ? тогда не просто никак, а вообще удавить эту мысль в колыбельке. Хочется непрерывной нумерации - делай для этой цели отдельное поле и заполняй его программно. PS. Если даже просто возникает желание посмотреть значение синтетического первичного ключа - значит, у тебя уже что-то неправильно.

Comment: Я даже дополню: "делай для этой цели отдельное поле и заполняй его программно" - и это тоже не выйдет, когда дойдете до параллельного выполнения в разных потоках и / или до отката транзакции.

Comment: @kami Прекрасно всё выйдет. Дополнительная нумерующая таблица + триггер. См. напр. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74515455/10138734 - там правда похожий (для заполнения дыр придётся делать таблицу MyISAM и переинициализировать автоинкремент) метод используется для совсем других целей, но какая разница... а при чём тут откаты, я вообще не понял. Автора не пугают дыры, он просто желает повторно использовать освободившиеся значения.

Comment: @kami Или можно совсем по старинке - через резервирование на основании номера соединения.

Comment: @Akina `повторно использовать освободившиеся значения` - да, проглядел. Ок, пусть будет так.